# How can I get a random number of element from list

Tags: c#, list, random

I am writing to You with small problem. I am writing small application in C#.NET MVC5, and I have one question, how can I get a few random items from List?

My code:

```
public ActionResult ProductsList()
{
    List<Product> products = productRepo.GetProduct().ToList();
    return PartialView(products);
}
```

This method return full list, how can I do it correctly?

Comment: What is meant by few, 2 or 3 or any number by specific?

Comment: Please, elaborate *few random items*. For instance, do you allow *repeating*? : `List[3], List[7], List[3]`? Shall the items be *ordered*: `List[3], List[8]` or `List[8], List[3]` will do as well?

Comment: 6 items can be good, without repeating

Comment: If you are getting products from database, you should consider doing randomness in database query. Retrieving each and every row and then randomizing in application server might result in huge amounts of data transfer depending on your data.

Comment: To get non-repeating random items you need to assign a random number to every item in the list.  Then sort list by random number.  Next take X number of items from the sorted list.  In you can I would add a property to your class "Product" call randomNumber to make it easy to sort you list.  Assign a random number to each item.  Then use OrderBy to sort the list "products" by the random number.  Then take the first 6 items in the sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random no and fetch the 6 elements of the list based on the random No. generated.

```
    public ActionResult ProductsList()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<Product> products = productRepo.GetProduct().ToList();
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNo = r.Next(1, products.Count);
        int itemsRequired = 6; 
        if (products.Count <= itemsRequired)
            return PartialView(products));
        else if (products.Count - randomNo >= itemsRequired)
            products = products.Skip(randomNo).Take(itemsRequired).ToList();
        else
            products = products.Skip(products.Count - randomNo).Take(itemsRequired).ToList();
        return PartialView(products));
```

Comment: How can i do minimal and maximal number of random elements? Now it give me random number of elements. I need 6 elements default, always.

Comment: @Giacomo, I've updated my answer for generating 6 elements always.

Comment: What if the initial list `products` has *too few* values? E.g. `3` only, when `itemsRequired = 6`? In your current code an *exception* will be thrown, when the best way out, IMHO, is to return the entire list.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko if parameter in Take() method has a value greater than the length of the list it will return the all the elements available and no exception will be thrown. Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Mahesh Chand when i start my app in Visual, on homepage i have 6 items, but when i refresh site it give me other random number of elements. In my database is now 7 items. Only for tests.

Comment: @Giacomo Are you talking about the different number of items or different items each time with same count?

Comment: "7 items" i mean my items in List (database), but i need 6 products on my homepage each time (always, random - each time same count(6))

Comment: @Giacomo I'm passing the same value i.e. itemsRequired to Take() method each time. Could you please add a breakpoint in code and look if you missed anything ?

Comment: When i debug it give me: products: Count=7, randomNo: 3, itemsRequired: 6. And on homepage i see only 3 products, and program is going to else if (products.Count - randomNo >= itemsRequired)
                products = products.Skip(randomNo).Take(itemsRequired).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

I suggest selecting out random indexes and then returning corresponding items:

```
// Simplest, not thread-safe
private static Random s_Random = new Random();

private static List<Product> PartialView(List<Product> products, int count = 6) {
  // Too few items: return entire list
  if (count >= products.Count)
    return products.ToList(); // Let's return a copy, not list itself

  HashSet<int> taken = new HashSet<int>();

  while (taken.Count < count)
    taken.Add(s_Random.Next(count));

  List<Product> result = new List<Product>(count);

  // OrderBy - in case you want the initial order preserved
  foreach (var index in taken.OrderBy(item => item))
    result.Add(products[index]);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of Random class somewhere. Note that it's pretty important not to create a new instance each time you need a random number. You should reuse the old instance to achieve uniformity in the generated numbers.

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
List<Product> products = productRepo.GetProduct().ToList();
int r = rnd.Next(products.Count);
products = products.Take(r).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will always take from the start of the list.

Comment: What if `rnd.Next(list.Count)` returns *zero*? Probably, an *emply list* is not a desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the Random class and make use of NEXT function which returns the non negative number below the specified limit...

```
List<Product> products = productRepo.GetProduct().ToList();

var randomProduct=new Random();

var index=randomProduct.Next(products.Count);

return PartialView(products[index]);
```

Hope this could help you..
Happy coding